# Why am I getting two answers here?

Tags: trigonometry

Why am I getting two answers here?Not able to find my mistake.

$\frac{Sin (A-B)}{-cos(A-B)} $= - Tan A-B

$\frac{Sin A- B}{Cos B-A)} $= -Sin (B-A)/cos B- A

Comment: $\cos(B-A)\neq-\cos(A-B)$.

Comment: cos is positive in I and IV quadrant... (Or, what @AndrewChin said

Comment: Policy is to post text versions of questions, not images. This is especially applicable as your writing is rather hard to read.

Comment: Ok sir I will do that next time.It is just easier to ask in image.Much faster and time consuming for everyone.

Comment: It actually is easier and faster to type this out than it is to take a picture, upload the picture, and include it in the post. At least to me it would be.

Comment: Use MathJax instead of posting pictures: If you do not want to learn rigourously, just type in https://www.desmos.com/calculator and copy the TeX from there and paste it here. It will make the question much more readable, and wont take a lot of time.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi I have started to use mathjax in my every post from now.Ok I will check on that too.

Comment: That's niee, I just came across a few of your not-so-well received questions and I found that you had issues while typing, so I shared an easy way which use quite often!

Comment: Yes Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $\sin$ is an odd function, $\cos$ is an even function.  The following symmetries apply:
$$\sin(A-B)=\sin(-(B-A))=-\sin(B-A)$$$$\cos(A-B)=\cos(-(B-A))=\cos(B-A)$$